# Through get Method, Getting Acces to Other Classes Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to access variable from one class to another. I tried help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883303/getting-acces-to-other-classes-variables) but it was on other way. I have a base class as following:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int MemberUserId
    {
        get
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
            if (user != null)
            {
                string memberUserId = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
                CustomerBL clientsBL = new CustomerBL ();
                Customers customer = CustomerBL .GetCustomer(memberUserId);
                int customerId = customer .CustomerId;
                return customerId;
            }
            return 0;
        }
  }

}
```

I want to get customerId to this class as following :

```
public partial class showCustomer : BasePage
{ 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadCustomerProfile();
        }
    }
    LoadCustomerProfile()
    {
       BasePage basePage;
       int customerId = basePage.customerId; //intellisense is not showing option of customerId
    }
}
```

when I type basePage.customerId, intellisense does not show customerId and gives error when i forcefully type it. I will be grate full if anyone help me out. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't created a `customerId` property. You've created a `MemberUserId` property.

That said, your code would still be invalid as you've declared the `basePage` local variable, but haven't assigned a value to it. Are you sure you don't just want:

```
int customerId = MemberUserId;
```

i.e. asking `this`?

Answer (score 4):

First of all don't make BasePage variable, second of all you have access to MemberUserId not customerId

```
LoadCustomerProfile()
{
   int customerId = this.MemberUserId; //this used for clarification
}
```

of course you can create other BasePage field called `customerId` and use it in showCustomer page.

I think you are trying to access MemberUserId because it's returning customerId here:

```
        int customerId = customer .CustomerId;
        return customerId;
```

Comment: thanx, I tried your first block of code and its working. I did not tried the second block. I will try it later on :)